# Point forces in linear elasticity and small strains

Tags: singularities, elasticity, continuum-mechanics, greens-functions

Consider a point force $\boldsymbol{F}=F\boldsymbol{e}_z$ in an infinite elastic material. In a linear approximation, the displacements can be calculated using Green's function for the Laplacian which gives $-1/(4\pi |\boldsymbol{r}|)$ for the displacements along $z$: thus not only the strain but also the displacement is infinite in the vicinity of the point force.

Now I am a bit confused about this: I think the only proper way to circumvent this is to go back to the small strain hypothesis and see that it fails in this case of a point force, but then how does one show that Green's function is giving the correct result away from the singularity? Does Green's function approximate the linear large-strain deformation if sufficiently far from it? Or do I forget something else that may be important (I don't think the bulk modulus would alleviate the singularity, would it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question sounds like a question about electricity and magnetism in disguise.  We make the replacements

1) force $\rightarrow$ charge

2) displacement $\rightarrow$ electric potential

and we look for solutions of Poisson's equation $\phi = -c \nabla^2 \rho$ where $\phi$ is the displacement (aka potential) and $\rho$ is a force per unit volume (aka charge density) and $c$ is some constant determined by our system of units.  The relevant Green's function here is proportional to $1/r$ in three spatial dimensions, as the questioner asserts.

The question then becomes a variant of "What should we do about the infinite self-energy of a point charge?"

An easy remedy to the divergence is to distribute the force over a small volume (equivalently the charge over a small volume).  Depending on the details of the smearing, the resulting displacement (equivalently electric potential) will be different close to the region where the force is applied.  Far away, however, we can treat the force as if it were all applied at a single point.

In one simple scenario, we smear the force evenly over the surface of a small sphere of radius $a$.  If the force is sufficiently small, the displacement will also be small and will fall off as $c F/4 \pi r$ for $r>a$ and will be a constant $c F/4 \pi a$ for $r<a$. (The answer here should be familiar to those who have taken a first year electricity and magnetism course.)

Comment: Thanks, the analogy is useful. Since you obtain the sphere result with Gauss's law, I guess I simply need to apply the divergence theorem on a sphere around the point force or small sphere.

Answer (score 1):

You are finding that you get an infinite displacement at the origin regardless of how small the force is. I believe you are concerned because the answer doesn't seem to respect the assumption that all displacements are small, and furthermore, you can't fix this issue by making the force smaller.

I think the usual way of fixing this problem is to imagine putting a rigid ball with a very small radius $a$ into the material, and apply a small force to this rigid ball. This "regulates" the divergence: the displacement of the ball will go to zero as the force goes to zero.

Now you can ask if this regulated problem gives you the same answer as the point force problem. For each finite $a$, you can be sure that you are in the linear regime, if you apply a small enough force. When you send the radius of the rigid ball, $a$, to zero, you should see the displacement field approaches a well-defined limit, and this limit (I think) is consistent with the point force answer. (In fact, the displacement field might be independent of $a$ when $r>a$—I can't remember.) Thus you see that your diverging point force solution is consistent with the regularized solutions. Thus this method is a good way of telling that the point force does really give you the right answer for the displacement.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. Can one use the Green's function to obtain the displacements for a finite $a$?